# String.fromCharCode(). превышение значения 16-битного числа

Tags: javascript, unicode

**String.fromCharCode()**

**Сводка**

> Статический метод **String.fromCharCode()** возвращает строку,
>   созданную из указанной последовательности значений Юникода.

**Примечание**

> Хотя большинство распространённых значений Юникода может быть
>   представлено одним 16-битным числом (как ожидалось на ранней стадии
>   стандартизации JavaScript) и метод `fromCharCode()` может
>   использоваться для возврата одного символа для самых распространённых
>   значений (точнее, значений UCS-2, которые являются подмножеством самых
>   распространённых символов UTF-16), для работы со ВСЕМИ допустимыми
>   значениями Юникода (занимающими до 21 бита) одного метода
>   `fromCharCode()` недостаточно. Поскольку большие кодовые точки
>   используют (самое меньшее) два «суррогатных» числа для представления
>   одного символа, для возврата таких пар можно использовать метод
>   [String.fromCodePoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint) (являющийся частью черновика ES6) и, таким
>   образом, адекватно представлять эти символы.

**String.fromCodePoint()**

**Сводка**

> Статический метод **String.fromCodePoint()** возвращает строку, созданную
>   из указанной последовательности кодовых точек.

**Пример:**

```js
console.log(String.fromCodePoint(119987)); //
```

```js
console.log(String.fromCharCode(119987)); // 풳
```

> Более старый метод `fromCharCode` в последней строке дал неверный
>   результат, так как он берёт только первые два байта от числа 119987 и
>   создаёт символ из них, а остальные отбрасывает.

**Математическая рукописная заглавная X `U+1D4B3`:**

**Техническая информация**

- Номер в Юникоде: `U+1D4B3`
- HTML-код: `&#119987;`
- Раздел   Математические буквенно-цифровые символы

**Вопрос:** **풳** в Unicode равен: `54451`, но метод `String.fromCharCode()` при передачи аргумента в виде числа `119987` выдает **풳**. Можете пояснить как так получилось. Выше написано что:

> ...так как он берёт только первые два байта от числа 119987

Поясните пожалуйста детально этот момент более популярно.

```js
console.log('풳'.codePointAt(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

> а остальные отбрасывает.

```
119987 - 54451 = 65536 = 2^16
```

Comment: по какому принципу это работает?